# Sublime text 3 overlapping file name and blank autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3

I just installed sublime text 3 build 3126 but i am having these two problems that I can't resolve. I enabled autocomplete in the setting but its showing a blank area, but if i hit enter I could get the completed result. And whenever I open, close or or make a new file, the tabs malfunction and are showing the overlapping file names. Please help me with these two. Thanks!

[image: Sublime text 3 build 3126 autocompletion and graphic problems]

Comment: looks like something is massively wrong with your theme - check the console for errors (View menu -> Show Console) or try https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/revert.html

Comment: @KeithHall thanks! Resetting worked! Not sure what happened there before.